# How can I read a C# Console app's entire command line, as it was typed?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, console-application

I am writing a little REPL console app, and I read a command, split it, and use a piss-poor switch statement to decide which method to call (instead of using the Strategy Pattern). I then place each command into a history, for audit.

The command line when starting the app, as typed, is lost as it is already split. I would prefer to have the whole command line and get on with my loop and it's own split routine.

Is it possible to get the whole command line somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the entire command line as originally passed to the program via

[`Environment.CommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

First choice is to join it again:

```
var arg = string.Join(" ", args);
```

If you want to do this out side main you can ger arguments as:

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()
```

Comment: Just a note that using Join won't include quotation marks, backslashes, or any other characters removed by the shell.

Comment: To summary: if a C# program `a.dll` (or `a.exe`) is called like `a.dll foo bar`, `Environment.CommandLine` returns a string `"C:\\Full\\Path\\To\\a.dll foo bar"`, while `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` returns an array of strings `{"C:\\Full\\Path\\To\\a.dll", "foo", "bar"}`. And FYI `Program.Main`'s `args` argument will be `{"foo", "bar"}`. Based on my testing results.